# is a fully working application required or will apple develop your idea

Tags: iphone

I have an idea for an app, but this is an idea only and not a fully functioning app, can anyone help with how I go about proceeding, firstly to see if this has not been thought of by anyone else, secondly how to develop my idea into a working app, or will apple do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by learning to code or hiring a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean an iPhone app idea.

Apple will not develop applications for you.

I would use one of the (many) application aggregation web sites such as http://appshopper.com/ (picked at random) to see if there already exists similar apps that are highly rated.

If your application idea has competitors in the Windows or OS X space, see if those companies already have apps.

There are companies you can hire to actually develop your program for you. Or post on some of the forums, such as modmyi, requesting programming help.